# I don't understand how I am getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, parsing, memory, fault

When I try to print each character of the file, I get segmentation fault. I don't understand why.

```
void parseStringAndDelete(char *file)
{
// I a passing "drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 Mar 07 12:34 A_Folder"
// as an argument for the function
 int i = 0;
 int k = 0;
 int len = strlen(file);
 int startIndex = 0;

 //printf("%s\n", file);
 //printf("%d\n", len);
 if(file[0] == 'd')
  {
      for(i = 0; i<len; i++)
      {
        printf("%s\n", file[i]);
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: I found the error. For printf("%c\n", file[i]) not printf("%s\n", file[i]). I believe because I am printing character by character not just one string.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and watch them.

Comment: Exactly: %s is for printing strings, %c is for printing characters. You should first learn to use a debugger, so at least you will find the line that crashes, not just "I get segmentation fault". Second, whenever you have a problem, you need to approach it by saying: "_I_ made a mistake somewhere. Which mistake did I make? " Never think: "My code is correct, why doesn't it work". Always think: "My code is wrong. Where is it wrong? "

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print each character of the string, then you should use `%c` and not `%s`.

```
printf("%c\n", file[i]);
```

---

Additionally,

When printing a string using `printf("%s", ..)`, you need to pass an address where the string is residing, not the content of the address.

So, for a `char* str = "hello"`, print statement would be

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

and NOT

```
printf("%s\n", str[0]);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants `printf("%c\n", file[i]);`

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I fixed the problem my switching %s to %c in printf